# Declaring type definition once for all variables

Tags: c#, object-oriented, classes, enum

To avoid the use of magic numbers, I created a static class to store some integer values that are represented inside a database. I avoided using enums because I need to cast them every time I use them. To benefit from the clean approach of enums while also enjoying the type definition offered by classes.

**The Class Approach**

```
public static class TransactionType
{
    public static readonly int
        Deposit = 1,
        Withdrawal = 2,
        Transfer = 3,
        Payment = 4,
        Refund = 5;
}

// Example Usage
public void ProcessTransactionClass(int transactionTypeId)
{
    if (transactionTypeId == TransactionType.Deposit)
    {
        // Handle deposit
    }
    else if (transactionTypeId == TransactionType.Withdrawal)
    {
        // Handle withdrawal
    }
    // ... and so on for other types
}
```

**Enum Approach**

```
public enum TransactionType
{
    Unassigned = 0, // Default value
    Deposit = 1,
    Withdrawal = 2,
    Transfer = 3,
    Payment = 4,
    Refund = 5
}

// Example Usage
public void ProcessTransactionEnum(int transactionType)
{
    if (transactionType == (int)TransactionType.Deposit)
    {
        // Handle deposit
    }
    else if (transactionType == (int)TransactionType.Withdrawal)
    {
        // Handle withdrawal
    }
    // ... and so on for other types
}
```

I haven't seen this kind of usage anywhere, is this style any good and acceptable?

Comment: This lacks context.  Can you also show example code where you use a TransactionType?  Also, any reason why you did not make them `const`?  I wonder if your resistance on casting to an `enum` to an  `int` is more a lack of understanding on your part.  Example usage code will be a big help in getting quality answers.

Comment: *enums because I need to cast them every time*  =>  perhaps a Dictionary w/ enum members as the key.

Comment: @RickDavin I provided an example. Using `const` the value will be stored inside the assembly which I don't want for various reasons. Like a change in a shared library would result in different values because it is determined at compile time

Comment: @radarbob Sorry, I really can't see the benefit here, could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Abcd, can you elaborate on why you won't cast enums. I assume you want to avoid the computation overhead.

Comment: Do not change the post in response to feedback. It make comments and answers invalid and confusing.

Comment: @radarbob I haven't made any changes which would change the context of my question. I just provided example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, after much back and forth I think I understand....

> I haven't seen this kind of usage anywhere, is this style any good and acceptable?

No. No it's not. Be consistent with Type usage. If these numbers are "kinds of transactions" then write the code that way. Do not flip flop all over the code base, it induces bug risk.

Use enums. They are Type safe. Mistakes are caught at compile time. Cast the DB sourced values to enums, not the other way around. Do this up front, probably in a constructor, THEN use them.

Comment: Aren't class fields type safe too?

Comment: @Abcd they're base type safe (int in this case), but they're not context-safe. Nothing stops you from writing `addressTypeId = TransactionType.Deposit` - they're both ints, but their contexts are completely different and assigning ints everywhere isn't safe. Use the enum and convert at the last mile.

Comment: shameless plug for an ID (integer, long, guid) that has an affinity to a type: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/159999/987

Answer (score 3):

I know that @radarbob says that your "class" in neither good style or acceptable, but I disagree.  **NOTE: this is NOT a critique of radarbob's answer.**  Rather, I am offering alternative perspective.

I have used some 3rd party C# SDK's that integrate with SQL Server tables.  They do like your originally had by using named constants rather than enums, as this more tightly integrates with the integers coming over from SQL.  I have seen it before, and do consider it acceptable.

The one thing I would change is to use `const` over `static readonly`.

Comment: I wonder the reasoning behind using const instead of readonly field. In another comment I expressed my concern and would like to know better.

Comment: @Abcd for your use case, it's better to use const instead. As the values are fixed, and they won't be changed. Unlike `static readonly` that used with values that needed to be assigned at runtime such as fetching the a values from the configurations.

Comment: *more tightly integrates with the integers coming over* => This is all well and good, it sounds like a fancy ORM. An ORM being a code layer whose Single Responsibility is to transliterate Domain values to/from DB form, effectively decouples the domain model from the storage medium. As long as you are not corrupting the model's Domain Specific Language with terms, values, types, and  code workarounds for the sake of the storage medium

Answer (score 2):

> I haven't seen this kind of usage anywhere, is this style any good and acceptable?

**enum Approach**

If you mean the `if else if` structure... a `switch` statement will be more concise, easier to read, and quicker to understand.

THIS

```
public void ProcessTransactionEnum(int transactionType)
```

SHOULD BE

```
public void ProcessTransactionEnum(TransactionType transactionType)
  if (transactionType == TransactionType.Deposit)  { ...
```

And `enums` can be compared without casting to the underlying `int` values.

---

---

[Here is an example touching on all the points below.](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/32977/10221)

You don't need to specify the `static` on enum. enum is static by default. [See this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4567894/463206)

Assigning explicit values to the enum members can be very beneficial. I like to make the enum default (zero) to be "unassigned", "unknown", etc. It is great for error checking and it avoids making initially wrong assignments, which is potential trouble.

> I avoided using enums because I need to cast them every time I use them.

Casting is process-expensive. So what? I don't see the need in the context of "transaction types."  In any case unless saving mere milliseconds is execution critical, I say take advantage of the coding happiness it gives to you, the reader, and maintenance programmer.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here. The example I provided is the `class` approach I wanted to replace with enums. I will edit my post to provide both versions and be clearer.

Comment: It is not just about the time saving, it also clutters the code with unnecessary syntax.

Comment: Currently working with a database model that is handled by edmx, which doesn't support enum types, we have to cast either the Lvalue or the Rvalue to use them as function parameters etc. Your proposal seems good as a general solution but not so good in this case.

Comment: *[the DB ... doesn't support enum types]*.  =>  That is irrelevant. The C# code is your "model", "domain". Write the code in that context.  The DB is merely a storage medium and should not be influencing business model design. Coupling by omission, I'd call it.